# PHP+Jquery - displaying values in a table

Tags: php, jquery

Good evening.

This construction displays the values in a table that sorts them in alphabetical order.Those for example, if you click on the D link, only the names with letter D should be shown, and so on.

PHP code:

```
<?php

include ('engine/api/api.class.php');
$table = 'dle_post';
$fields  = 'xfields';
$where = 'approve=1';
$multirow = 1;
$start = 0;
$limit = 0;
$xfield = 'actor';
$time = '14000';
$tr_new = 0;

$xfields = $dle_api->load_from_cache ($fields, $time, $xfields);
if( !$xfields ) { 
    $xfields = $dle_api->load_table ($table,$fields,$where,$multirow,$start,$limit); 
    $dle_api->save_to_cache ( xfields, $xfields); 
    }

$stack = array(); 
foreach($xfields as $value){  
    if($value[xfields]){ 

        $row = xfieldsdataload($value[xfields]); 
        if($row[$xfield]){ 

            $rowdata = explode( ",", $row[$xfield]); 
            foreach($rowdata as $value){    
                if($value){                    
                    $value = trim($value);    
                    array_push($stack, $value); 
                    asort($stack);         
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
$stack = array_count_values($stack); 
foreach($stack as $key => $count){  

if($tr_new === 0){ 
    echo '<tr class="new">';
    }

    echo "<td class='blok'>"; 
    echo "<a href=/" . $xfield . "/";  
    echo $key; 
    echo " target='_blank' rel='noopener'>";
    echo $key; 
    echo "</a>"; 
    echo "<span>";  
    echo "(" . $count . ")";
    echo "</span>"; 
    echo "</td>"; 

    $tr_new++; 
    if($tr_new === 1){ 
    echo '</tr>';
    $tr_new = 0;
    }
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var _alphabets = $('.alphabet > a');
    var _contentRows = $('#countries-table tbody tr');

    _alphabets.click(function () {
        var _letter = $(this), _text = $(this).text(), _count = 0;
        if(_text == 'all') _text = '.';

        _alphabets.removeClass("active");
        _letter.addClass("active");

        _contentRows.hide();
        _contentRows.each(function (i) {
            var _cellText = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
            if (RegExp('^' + _text).test(_cellText)) {
                _count += 1;
                $(this).fadeIn(400);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In page:

```
<div class="alphabet">
<a class="first" href="#">All</a>
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">B</a>
<a href="#">C</a>
...
<a class="last" href="#">Z</a></div>
<div id="conutries">
<table id="countries-table">
<tbody>
{include file="/code.php"}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine, but I encounter such a problem - it turns out correctly to output only one value in one line tr ...
[image: display 1 td in row]

When I try to put a 4 td values to the tr line `if($tr_new === 4)` - they are not sort by alphabetically, they just displayed like this:
[image: display 4 td in row]

Whats wrong? What need to make this code work fine for me?
Thank you in advance for your help!